# Cpanel file permissions change automatically after system backup

Tags: backup, cpanel

I've configured auto legacy backup.
Every time it does a system backup, all the 777 permissions will change to something like 750 and it causes 500 server error.
Can anyone tell me how to stop this from happening. It resets the permissions every time I do a backup.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting this issues for your all account ?

I think it's not due to backup. Might be there is other cron which is changing the account files permission from 777 to 755.

You can test this by disabling backup cron for one day and check account's file permission.

Comment: Yes it's for all of the accounts.

Comment: What cronjob. I don't set any cronjob for that. Help me please